# SimpleHTTPServer not working

Tags: python, simplehttpserver

I'm connecting to a VPN (Linux machine) through ssh and invoke the following command there:

```
sibi::bash-> python -m SimpleHTTPServer
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 ...
```

Then, I visit it in it's URL: http://x.x.x.x:8000 and the browser complains me that it is not able to connect.

How to debug this issue ?

( Apache's test page works fine in http://x.x.x.x )

Updated: IP Rules (iptables -L -n)

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:22 
REJECT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
REJECT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Comment: You are connecting to port 8080 but the server is shown as listening to port 8000... Note the difference, count the number of `8` and `0` digits in that.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Sorry, updated the question.

Comment: Does your VPN machine have a firewall? Most likely port 8000 is blocked (as would most ports be).

Comment: @MartijnPieters I don't think so, that's the problem. Have updated the IP rules.

Comment: And `telnet localhost 8000` on the VPN, after starting the server, works?

Comment: @MartijnPieters No, connection is refused.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41469/discussion-between-sibi-and-martijn-pieters)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was clearly an firewall issue.

Flushing the `iptables` helped in resolving the issue:

`sudo iptables -F`

But be careful, you may want to set up  proper firewall rules for your VPN server.